# Is the Folium of Descartes a smooth curve?

Tags: calculus

The Folium of Descartes,

$$x^3+y^3=3axy$$ differentiatiing gives $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{ay-x^2}{y^2-ax}$$

Is it possible that $y^2 = ax$? I looked up on wikiapedia that under the parametrization $y = px$, the curve is not smooth. Is it possible to make it a smooth?

Comment: The curve self-intersects at $(0,0)$. Does that conflict with your definition of smoothness? On the other hand, it certainly looks like it has _some_ smooth parameterization, such as parameterizing by the angle between each point on the curve and $(1,1)$.

Comment: Agreed. Usually a smooth curve is defined as an injective immersion from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I tried making the obvious substitution $x = t$, it would appear that $x' = 1$ and this perhaps makes it impossible for the curve to be smooth.

Comment: If you try googling "Folium of Descartes" you will quickly find sketches of the curve that make it apparent that parameterizing by $x$ is a non-starter -- the $x$ coordinate needs to decrease some of the time! But a circle has the same problem, and if a circle is not smooth, then what is?

Comment: I just found the same problem if $x = t$. It seems that it is still possible to be not smooth because of the origin.

Comment: @WilliamStagner, I am not familiar with the term. My definition of smoothness is if the curve is of class $C^\infty$

Comment: Under any parameterization, what is the tangent vector at (0, 0)? I think self intersection precludes this curve being smooth.

Comment: @WilliamStagner, ah that is a much more sound argument since it behaves like a cusp at the origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a smooth curve because it intersects itself.

Comment: Shouldn't this be "It isn't"?